# How to display images thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, carrierwave

In my rails app, I'm trying to implement a private gallery using carrierwave gem. Only owner of the gallery can visit gallery and sees images.

On the gallery show page these images should be displayed as thumbnails.
I'm using reactjs for the view layer [react_webpack_rails](https://github.com/netguru/react_webpack_rails)

For single image i can use `send_file` or `send_data` but these  methods only open or download the image inside my browser and whats worse i cannot use them with ajax request.

Summary:
In this situation, what is a correct and the most efficient way to pass images/data from rails controller to the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can use [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) gem to make your thumbnails easy.

Then you could just put images you need at the cloud service like Cloudinary or Amazon S3 and store the links to it in your DB. In that way you could initialize in your controller's action some images and render them in your view.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I have to try it.

Comment: Glad to help you!